# How to delay an option becoming available inside a function?

Tags: python

I have a dungeon crawler game I'm working on and in the function that decides what room the player enters I want to be able to delay the exit room from becoming available until the player has entered a certain amount of rooms. Here is the function:

```
def room_enter(empty_room, ghost_room, monster_room, exit_room, crumbly_room, locked_room, surgery_room, prisoner_encounter):
    global player_health
    global room_count
    security = True
    while security == True:
        direction = input("\nYou have the option to go Left (l), Forward (f), or Right (r), which direction would you like to go? ")
        print("\n ")
        if direction == "l" or direction == "f" or direction == "r":
            security = False
            room_no = random.randint(1,16)

            if room_no == 1 or room_no == 2 or room_no == 3:
                empty_room()
                room_count = room_count + 1
            if room_no == 4 or room_no == 5:
                ghost_room()
                room_count = room_count + 1
            if room_no == 6:
                monster_room()
                room_count = room_count + 1
            if room_no == 7 or room_no == 16:
                exit_room()
                room_count = room_count + 1
            if room_no == 8 or room_no == 9:
                crumbly_room()
                room_count = room_count + 1
            if room_no == 10 or room_no == 11:
                locked_room()
                room_count = room_count + 1
            if room_no == 12 or room_no == 13:
                surgery_room()
                room_count = room_count + 1
            if room_no == 14 or room_no == 15:
                prisoner_encounter()
                room_count = room_count +1
        else:
            print("\nInvalid Entry")
```

Comment: Side comments: 1) Stop using `global` variables, 2) use `elif` when `if` statements are mutually exclusive

Answer (score 0):

You can test multiple options using `in`:

```
if direction in "lfr":
```

You really don't need the `security` variable because you can just `break` when you get a valid `input`.

```
while True:
    if direction in "lfr":
        ...
        break
```

Assuming you just want an `empty_room()` instead of `exit_room()` if `room_count < certain_number_room` then you put an extra guard:

```
if room_no in {7, 16}:
    if room_count < 5:
        empty_room()
    else:
        exit_room()
```

Given you are incrementing your `room_count` with every option just move it outside the `if` statements:

```
    if direction in "lfr":
        ...
        room_count += 1
        break
```

Personally, if the check is short I prefer to test the negative and `continue` vs having a big indented block. Putting it all together you get:

```
while True:
    direction = input("\nYou have the option to go Left (l), Forward (f), or Right (r), which direction would you like to go? ")
    print("\n ")
    if direction not in "lfr":
        print("\nInvalid Entry")
        continue

    room_no = random.randint(1,16)

    if room_no in {1, 2, 3}:
        empty_room()
    elif room_no in {4, 5}:
        ghost_room()
    elif room_no in {6}:
        monster_room()
    elif room_no in {7, 16}:
        if room_count < 5:
            empty_room()
        else:
            exit_room()
    elif room_no in {8, 9}:
        crumbly_room()
    elif room_no in {10, 11}:
        locked_room()
    elif room_no in {12, 13}:
        surgery_room()
    elif room_no in {14, 15:
        prisoner_encounter()
    room_count += 1
    break
```

I would look to avoid the use of `global` variables, perhaps look at encapsulation with a `class`.

Answer (score 0):

I would rewrite the whole thing in the OOP manner. Your code just has too many logical branches to follow that it becomes unmanageable ang "bug-friendly". Use class attributes to keep the state and you will be just fine.

Furthermore,  using the global keyword you pose your code at risk of the developer's inability to keep matters under control.